# Estimating biomass in mangroves in google earth engine

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, land-cover

I am working on a project estimating biomass production and carbon storage in mangrove forests.

I looked upon examples estimating biomass production using NPP and GPP such as https://mygeoblog.com/2016/10/19/biomass-production-from-npp/ and https://mygeoblog.com/2016/10/18/measuring-carbon-storage-from-space/ .

These examples are using Modis MOD17A3H.006: Net Primary Production Yearly L4 Global 500 m and MYD17A2H.006: Gross Primary Productivity 8-Day L4 Global 500 m  data.

But these products are lacking data in mangroves sites (I am focussing on Sundarbans and some other mangrove sites in India). Of which I think the reason is that wetlands are assigned fill values https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod17a2h_v006 and https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod17a3h_v006 .

Can anyone guide me what dataset would be best for mangroves? Can you guide with examples and algorithm to use?

Comment: GIS SE isn't a tutorial site. We use a "Focused question / Best answer" model, mostly to recover from stumbling blocks. Questions seeking broad guidance are likely to be closed as *too broad*, as are Questions with multiple questions.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for being so much helpful (not). 

I have been on stack-overflow for many years, working on different technologies. Starting with GIS related projects just a few weeks back. 
Have been helping and asking for help in stackoverflow and its a better community. 
Now I feel that GIS community is too much arrogant and not ready for sharing their experiences.

Comment: This remote sensing (RS)-focused question seems in scope for GIS SE. Specifically, https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic states "Geographic Information Systems is a question and answer site for people interested in GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned." The post is quite narrowly focused (i.e. best dataset for deriving NPP and GPP for mangroves). The post does include 2 questions, but they are highly interrelated... this is common for RS as algorithms are often dependent on the underlying dataset(s).

Comment: Disappointed with the community, Now they have put the question on hold. I have just asked what dataset would be best to estimate biomass/carbon content in mangroves and if anyone could show some examples. 
But GIS community doesn't want to help a new guy and by putting the question on hold, they won't let any other guy to help.

Comment: @TylerErickson Thanks for editing the question and adding appropriate tags :)

Comment: This is interesting. What RS product do you need to create your own NPP or GPP data? Which spectral bands? I think you need to start in basis before to select the "best" dataset

Comment: @Vince I am sure you (and the other moderators) have good reasons for flagging this as "too broad". I would like to help this user, but it is not clear to me why this question was flagged (even after I reread "How to Ask"). It appears to be in the general class of questions "How do you estimate a property (GPP/NPP) for a particular landcover class (mangroves) using a particular remote sensing analysis software package (Google Earth Engine)?" Is that general type of question too broad, or is it the particular content of this question? Is it using the term "best", which would invite opinions?

Comment: I am *not* a moderator. If you wish to communicate with one, you can flag the question, or you can fashion a question in [meta]

Comment: @vance apologies for incorrectly referring to you and others as moderators. As someone who put the question on hold, would you be willing to describe the specific aspects (see my earlier comment) that are too broad, so I might help the author improve it?

Comment: @GauravVashisth if you are not able to edit this post into a "Focused question / Best answer" format that is acceptable for GIS SE, I would recommend posting it to the [Google Earth Engine Developers List](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#the-earth-engine-developers-list), which supports general discussions on remote sensing analysis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1